# Facebook Page Tab Aplication external link

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have been creating one little facebook page tab for my company and I have encountered on problem.

I need to link to another website

```
<a href="https://example.ly" class="btn btn-success">Visit my website</a>
```

But facebook wont open linked webside, instead show empty page. Is there some trick how to do this? Some specific tag I need to add somewhere or how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page tab app is shown inside an iframe on facebook.com. Likely that other site sends an `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header, forbidding the browser to display it in 3rd-party (i)frames.

But presumably you don’t want to display that page inside the iframe to begin with? Then simply add a `target="_blank"` to the link, to have it open in a new tab.